# load php extension in windows

Tags: windows, dll, php-extension

I have a problem loading my extension in php in windows 7.
I've already installed php and IIS on my windows and when I check the phpinfo() page I find out that my extension_dir is c:/php/ext. so I copy my dll file in to that directory and also add `extension=php_mylib.dll` to php.ini file, then I restart the IIS and check if my extension has been loaded:

```
<?PHP
if (dl('php_mylib.dll')){ print ("YES")}
else{ print ("NO")}
?>
```

But I got "NO" every time I run this code. I appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem today on a slightly different system -
Win 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5 / PHP 5.3.9 nts

I was looking to enable php_printer.dll for network printing. Haven't found a resolution that doesn't involve compiling the dll, but I did learn someone had enabled safe mode.

This information is from the manual @ [function.dl.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php).

Information posted 7 years ago helped me out, seems appropriate for my system.

Here are the parts I found useful, from mag_2000 at front dot ru:

```
//make sure that we are ABLE to load libraries
if( !(bool)ini_get( "enable_dl" ) || (bool)ini_get( "safe_mode" ) ) {
  die( "dh_local(): Loading extensions is not permitted.\n" );
}

//check to make sure the file exists
if( !file_exists( $extensionFile ) ) {
 die( "dl_local(): File '$extensionFile' does not exist.\n" );
}

//check the file permissions
if( !is_executable( $extensionFile ) ) {
  die( "dl_local(): File '$extensionFile' is not executable.\n" );
}
```

Hope that helps!